# Slides justification in TeXnicCenter

Tags: horizontal-alignment, presentations

I could not use the justification in slide presentation. In TeXnicCenter there is center, left alignment and right alignment but I did not see the justification. Is there anyway so that I can fix it.

Comment: The default alignment for LaTeX documents is *justified*. Anything else have to be specified, so just remove any such formatting. What "presentation" document class are you using? Even better, provide a small, yet minimal, compilable example of a document with a slide that you want to have the justification for set.

Comment: Now you know that the problem is not related to the editor being used so in my opinion, the `texniccenter` tag should be removed.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are using `beamer` which by default uses `\raggedright`. To obatin justified text (but first ask yourself if this is really waht you want), you can load the `ragged2e` package and use `\justifying` in the preamble; this, however, won't have effect on environments such as `enumerate`, `itemize`, beamer blocks, etc., for which you will have to issue `\justifying` internally:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\justifying

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}\justifying
  \item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{alertblock}{Test}\justifying
  \lipsum[2]
\end{alertblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Rajesh: you're welcome! Since my answer apparently solved your problem, please consider accepting it (by clicking in the checkmark below the vote count).